# restarting kernel in a loop in python

Tags: python, api, jupyter, restart

I am trying to run a code using the api and the problem is it aborts the connection every few times and the only way to fix is to restart the kernel. I was wondering if there is any way in python to restart the kernel in try/except format inside a loop that runs every 5 minutes?

Something like this:

def execution():

```
try:

    main_code()
except:
    while check_connection != True:
        try:                        
            connection_command (to the api)
            break
        except:
            restart_kernel
    main_code()
```

In the above I am trying to see if the connection to api is good, if not restart the kernel and re-establish the connection.

Is it even possible?

Thank you

Comment: What prevents you from trying and to let us know what goes wrong, if any ?

Comment: Oh I did try. I got a range of different errors, some are related to my connection that does not get established (there is a github forum just for connection errors to this api and I just did not want to bring it here). I know I can get my connection established but every few minutes it aborts and then I usually manually restart the kernel and then I can establish the connection again. My whole effort here is to avoid this manual step and let the system run and if there is any connection abortion, it restarts the kernel and continue running my main_code.